# Does Spring Security issuer url support service by name using a discovery-service?

Tags: spring-security, spring-authorization-server

I have a authorization server running and is registered on my eureka discovery service with name `authorization-server`.  For one of my microservice I am using that authorization-server name for spring-security as follows:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: http://authorization-server
```

When I make a call to this microservice that has the above config I get this error when I send in a jwt claim:

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: Failed to resolve 'authorization-server' [A(1), AAAA(28)] after 12 queries
```

It seems like I can't use a discoverable service name for the issuer url.  Is that right or am I not using a correct convention?

Comment: I'd be curious to know why you downvoted my answer

Comment: Looks like you updated your answer.  I just wanted to know if the spring security supported  service discovery.  I was not looking for what you had described earlier.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to "Does Spring Security issuer url support service by name using a discovery-service?" is "probably not": if present, the `issuer-uri` is used for two things:

- add an issuer validator to the JwtDecoder. This validator Will require access tokens `iss` claim to be exactly what you define in your conf (even trailing slash, if any, is important)
- if `jwk-set-uri` property is missing, try to fetch OpenID configuration (at URIs like `{issuer-uri}/.well-known/openid-configuration`) and then the JWK-set from the endpoint it finds in this conf.

So, unless the authorization server uses its name in the discovery service to set the `iss` claim in the access tokens it emits, you can't use this name as `issuer-uri` in Spring Boot configuration.

Given your current conf (no jwk-set-uri), using the "public" name for the authorization-server should solve your problem. You'll find this URI in any access token (https://jwt.io can help you read an access token payload).

But there are actually three options:

- you are not interested in the issuer validation, then omit the `issuer-uri` property and define just the `jwk-set-uri`
- you want the issuer validation and the resource server can reach the Authorization server using the URI in `iss` claim of access-tokens, then use that URI for setting `issuer-uri` in your conf (and, if your authorisation server is OIDC, omit `jwk-set-uri` in your conf, it will be automatically resolved)
- you want the issuer validation but the resource server can not reach the Authorization server using the URI in `iss` claim of access-tokens, then use that URI anyway for setting `issuer-uri` in your conf and set the `jwk-set-uri`

When set (the last two cases) the hostname used in `jwk-set-uri` is resolved on the resource server and must be accessible from there to fetch the tokens public signing key.